# How to access form data posted in javascript without a submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create a live search bar that open the result when a suggestion is clicked but i don't know how to submit the form data through javascript to php page that generates pages depending on the suggestion clicked. 
So far the search bar displays suggestions as links but all items are displayed instead of just one

JAVASCRIPT CODE AND SEARCH FORM

```
    </style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
  //  $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
  //      $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
  //      $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
//});
</script>
<body>

    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for liquor..."  />
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

PHP CODE THAT DOES THE QUERYING

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "charles", "shoppingcartdemo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST["term"]);

if(isset($term)){
    // Attempt select query execution
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM shopping_items WHERE item_name LIKE '" . $term . "%'";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $linka = "profile.php";
                $resulta = $rows["item_name"];


             echo " <p> <a href= " .$linka. "> $resulta </a> </p> " ;



            }

            // Close result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else{
            echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }


}


// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

So

1. How do i submit the data from the form to a profile.php so it can generate a new page every time a link is clicked by a user
2. How do i access the data/variable from the profile.php page

Comment: Are you against changing the suggestions from links to buttons that change the value of the search input to whatever their value is?

Comment: If you are, you can maybe change them from links to submit buttons with the same name but their values would be the text they are displaying, so you can get the value from their name in php the normal way

Comment: @KevinLewis. Hadn't though of that. I'll try it out. can you please give me a guideline on where i should change my code? Thanks in advance

Comment: Ya, look at my first answer and it should have a guideline.  I don't know what the backend-search.php looks like, but replace your code that starts with $term = with my code querying code I showed.

Answer (score 1):

In the backend-search.php, I would format the returned items like this:

```
<input type = “submit” name = “sub-with-link” value = “whatever the innerHTML of the link is”>
```

Then, in the querying code, I would use something like the following:

```
 $submit_term = $_REQUEST[‘sub-with-link’];
if ($submit_term != “”) {
    $term = $submit_term;
} else {
    $term = $_REQUEST[‘term’];
}
```

By the way, I have not tested this and am not 100% sure if it would work, but I’ve dealt with similar stuff. If this doesn’t work, please tell me

Comment: This would require you having a form and works so that they can also search with a button, but that can be easily changed by deleting the if statement. I somewhat misunderstood the current code when I wrote this.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another way to do it.  The links don’t have to open a page, just make them call a function like such:

```
<a onclick =“change_submit(this) href =“#”>...<\a>
```

This would be the js code

```
function change_submit(data) {
  Input(use a selector, the input does not have an id currently.value = data.innerHTML;
  Form(use a selector, form should exist but apparently doesn’t).submit;
}
```

Comment: This would require you having a form and works so that they can also search with a button, but the submit button is not necessary. I somewhat misunderstood the current code when I wrote this.